# migrating/replacing Magento 1.3 data to maganeto 1.6

Tags: mysql, database, magento

We have a Magento 1.3 project and we want it to upgrade it into magento 1.6.
so We Install a new magento 1.6, Now we want to put all the products and customers data from maganeto 1.3 to magento 1.6. We back up all the products and customers data in its database tables from the magento 1.3.

these are the tables that We backed up the datas:

```
-------------------------------------
Product Tables:
-------------------------------------
catalogrule /
catalogrule_product /
catalogrule_product_price /
catalogrule_affected_product /

catalogindex_price /
catalogindex_eav /
catalogindex_minimal_price /
catalogindex_aggregation_tag /
catalogindex_aggregation /
catalogindex_aggregation_to_tag /

catalogsearch_query /
catalogsearch_fulltext /
catalogsearch_result /
catalog_compare_item /

catalog_category_product /
catalog_category_product_index /
catalog_category_flat_1 /

catalog_product_entity_tier_price /
catalog_product_enabled_index /
catalog_product_website /

catalog_category_entity /
catalog_category_entity_datetime /
catalog_category_entity_decimal /
catalog_category_entity_int /
catalog_category_entity_text /
catalog_category_entity_varchar /

catalog_product_entity /
catalog_product_entity_datetime /
catalog_product_entity_decimal /
catalog_product_entity_gallery /
catalog_product_entity_int /
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery /
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value /
catalog_product_entity_text /
catalog_product_entity_varchar /

catalog_product_super_link /
catalog_product_link_type /
catalog_product_link /
catalog_product_link_attribute /
catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal /
catalog_product_link_attribute_int /
catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar /

catalog_product_option/
catalog_product_option_title /
catalog_product_option_price /
catalog_product_option_type_value /
catalog_product_option_type_title /
catalog_product_option_type_price /

cataloginventory_stock /
cataloginventory_stock_status /
cataloginventory_stock_item /

catalog_product_bundle_option /
catalog_product_bundle_option_value /
catalog_product_bundle_selection /
catalog_product_bundle_price_index /

catalog_product_super_attribute //
catalog_product_super_attribute_label/
catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing /

product_alert_price /
product_alert_stock /

downloadable_link_price /
downloadable_link_title /
downloadable_link  /
downloadable_sample_title /
downloadable_sample /

----------------------------------------------
Customers Tables :
----------------------------------------------
customer_group/

newsletter_template /
newsletter_queue/
newsletter_queue_store_link/
newsletter_problem/
newsletter_queue_link/
newsletter_subscriber/

customer_entity/
customer_entity_datetime/
customer_entity_decimal/
customer_entity_int/
customer_entity_text/
customer_entity_varchar/

customer_address_entity/
customer_address_entity_datetime/
customer_address_entity_decimal/
customer_address_entity_int/
customer_address_entity_text/
customer_address_entity_varchar/

review_entity/
review_status/
review/
review_store/
review_entity_summary/
review_detail/

rating_entity/
rating/
rating_store/
rating_option
rating_option_vote/
rating_title/
rating_option_vote_aggregated/

poll/
poll_store/
poll_answer/
poll_vote/

wishlist/
wishlist_item/
```

then We delete all products and customers data in its database tables in the magento 1.6. Now, when we restore the backed up data from magento 1.3 to 1.6, We got this error...

```
Query:
/*Data for the table `catalog_category_entity` */
insert  into `catalog_category_entity`(...)

Error occured at:2012-09-12 14:05:06
Line no.:20
Error Code: 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I was just wondering that, why it became "Duplicate entry for primary key" when I deleted all the old data in the magento 1.6?

Does anyone have an idea about my case? Can you give me another Idea about on how can I transfer all products and customers data from magento 1.3 to 1.6?

any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better way:

- turn of caching
- turn off all custom local and community extensions
- turn off all local core overwrites
- turn off all custom themes and theme customisations
- regenerate indexes
- copy in 1.6 or latest Magento code
- fire the upgrade and be done with it